# Material won't apply to part of mesh

Tags: mesh, materials

I've been following the [Blender Guru anvil modeling tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yi87Dap_WOc), and I've finished the first 4 parts, which only includes modeling and fixing some topology.
After I finished modeling, I decided to apply a basic material to see how it would look, but somehow the cutout and the bottom of the mesh are not showing it.

I've tried everything I could think of short of starting from scratch, and it's driving me crazy!
Here [(link)](https://blend-exchange.com/b/2RVqDn7A/) is my blend file, I'd appreciate it if y'all could take a look.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heyo,
Go into edit mode (Tab) select the whole mesh (A), go to your material setting, click the Material with the small ball icon, and hit assign.

By clicking assign and having parts (or the whole) of the mesh selected in edit mode, you can tell blender which material you want on what faces.
I'm not 100% sure how you managed to have a part without any material while only having 1 single material on the model...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you see, these faces are assigned to a slot that has no material, the easiest way to fix it is to switch back to *Object* mode and remove this slot, or select all these faces and assign them the first material:

[image]